# JSF onclick radio button hide/show textbox

Tags: html, jsf

I want to implement functionality like, when I'm selecting one radio button it has to show one text box otherwise it should be in the hidden state. I wrote code like this

```
          <tr>
            <th><label for="selection">Register as ::</label></th>
            <td>        <h:selectOneRadio id="selection" value="#{LoginBean.role}" label="Action" required="true">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Customer" itemLabel="Customer" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Manager" itemLabel="Manager" />
                            <p:ajax process="console" update="@form" />
                        </h:selectOneRadio>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th><h:outputLabel value="Enter your Fee ::" rendered="#{LoginBean.role eq 'Manager'}"></h:outputLabel></th>
            <td><h:inputText id="fee" value="#{LoginBean.fee}" rendered="#{LoginBean.role eq 'Manager'}" required="true" requiredMessage="Fee is required." class="form-control"  a:placeholder="200.00" ></h:inputText></td>
          </tr>
```

Here, If I select Manager radio button it should show the outputLabel and inputeText.
There are getter and setters in the Bean Class.

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

instead of the input row as in your code,
I would recommend you put it in another form with rendered="#{LoginBean.isManager }", take out both rendered in your h tag.
Duplicate this form without any child tag, this form comes with rendered="#{!LoginBean.isManager }"

In your Bean, declare new boolean isManager with getter setter.
As you process your radio choice form, Bean will set isManager to false or true based on your choice and render the form according to your isManager.
I used this way to quick add "Edit" form. It works without POSTBACK. I hope it works for you!


PS: You may only need to set rendered to tr tag instead of h tag.

Comment: Please have a look at [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is giving error here  rendered="#{!LoginBean.isManager }" like "Cannot apply expression operators to method bindings". I don't understand when it will set isManager value. I have to write something in Manager radio button. Am I right?

Comment: The rendered attribute I provided is an example instance only, isManager property should be matched your boolean property in specified bean.
For my instance, in bean, I have:
`private boolean isManager`
come with getter setter. In your instance, I assume `isManager` now is a getter method(as `isManager(){...}` instead of `isManager;` which shouldn't be used on JSF page, as it is not valid.

Comment: This is an example to "my bean" https://pastebin.com/EnUv1whT
I'm just a freshly new Java fresher, my approach may not be optimized, but this does work in my training project.